# AutoCompleteTextView OnItemClick position is always "0"

Tags: android, autocomplete

the adapter works fine, but i don't understand why the position in OnItemClick is always "0"

```
String[] regions = ct.getRegions();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, regions);
    regionT.setAdapter(adapter);
    regionT.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 int pos=position;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but the argument `position` in method `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` holds the index relative to the `AutoCompleteTextView`'s dropdown list, not the position in your adapter array (in your case `regions`)!

So, to find the item's real `position` you must get the string selected in the dropdown and find its index in the adapter array:

```
String[] regions = ct.getRegions();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, regions);
regionT.setAdapter(adapter);
regionT.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selected = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        int pos = Arrays.asList(regions).indexOf(selected);
    }
});
```

Comment: Even better if your `ArrayAdapter's`  type is an object, you can assign it with `Object object = (Object) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: How is this suppose to work, if position is always 0?

I have the same issue as the original poster.

Comment: adapter.getItem(position) does the magic...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: I couldn't manage to get the position, but I've figured out how to retrieve the whole object selected by the user (if any), having an ID field, which in my case is all I need.
The trick is not to use an `ArrayAdapter<String>` for the suggested items, but an `ArrayAdapter<MyObject>`, where `MyObject` overrides the `toString()` method.
For instance:

```
public class Country extends Object {

  public int id;

  public Country(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    switch (id) {
      case 0:
        return "Albania";
      case 1:
        return "Romania";
      case 2:
        return "Ucraina";
      case 3:
        return "Russia";
      default:
        return "Unknwon";
    }
  }

}
...
private AutoCompleteTextView mNationAtv;
private Button mTestBtn;
private final Country[] COUNTRIES = {
  new Country(0),
  new Country(1),
  new Country(2),
  new Country(3)
};
...
// use object array for adapter
ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
mNationAtv.setAdapter(adapter);
mTestBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ArrayAdapter<Country> ada = (ArrayAdapter<Country>) mNationAtv.getAdapter();
    int nItems = ada.getCount();
    // default Country unknown
    Country selItem = new Country(5);
    if (nItems > 0) {
      selItem = (Country) ada.getItem(0);
    }
    Log.d(TAG,
        "onClick(): nItems=" + nItems + ", selItem.name=" + selItem.toString()
            + ", selItem.id=" + selItem.id);
  }

});
...
```

Logs:

- when the `AutocompleteTextView` value matches an item in the dropdown:
  `onClick(): nItems=1, selItem.name=Ucraina, selItem.id=2`
- when the value is blank:
  `onClick(): nItems=4, selItem.name=Albania, selItem.id=0`
- when the value isn't blank but doesn't match any item in the dropdown:
  `onClick(): nItems=0, selItem.name=Unknown, selItem.id=5`

You might want to fetch this value in the `OnItemClickListener()::onItemClick()` method, invoked avery time the user clicks an item in the dropdown, or outside of it, i.e. for validation.

Answer (score -2):

I put this in a simple example and it works correctly for me.  See below:

```
package com.example.autocompletetv;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AutoCompleteActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final String TAG = AutoCompleteActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_complete);

        String[] regions = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, regions);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);

        this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i(TAG, "postion was " + position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.auto_complete, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I click I get:

```
12-09 19:13:30.617: I/AutoCompleteActivity(1883): postion was 2
12-09 19:13:31.997: I/AutoCompleteActivity(1883): postion was 3
12-09 19:13:34.687: I/AutoCompleteActivity(1883): postion was 4
12-09 19:13:37.028: I/AutoCompleteActivity(1883): postion was 0
```

Comment: You don't include a full set of code, but it could be that regionT isn't the correct object on which to set the listener.  Are you using a ListActivity?